# Symfony2 : can't duplicate site because of strange folders architecture

Tags: windows, symfony, installation, symlink

I have to retrieve an existing symfony2 (2.1.13) project from prod server in order to run it locally to make some changes. The problem is the architecture seems to be a little bit strange. Please have a look on it :

```
$pwd
/var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com

drwxr-xr-x  2 ... 4.0K Jun 30 09:30 backups/
drwxr-x---  2 ...    6 Mar 15  2013 cgi-bin/
drwxr-xr-x  4 ...   41 Aug 10 18:09 _copie1/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ...    6 Apr 25  2014 log/
drwxr-xr-x 12 ... 4.0K Aug 11 15:41 releases/
drwxr-xr-x  7 ...  146 May 12 16:46 repo/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ...   85 May 12 16:49 shared/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ...   58 Jul  6 15:11 current -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ...   12 Mar 28  2013 html -> current/web//
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 1022 Jul  6 15:11 revisions.log

current/
drwxr-xr-x  6 ... 4.0K Jul  6 15:09 app/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ...  124 Jul  6 15:05 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  4 ...   50 Aug 11 14:54 src/
drwxr-xr-x 35 ... 4.0K Aug 11 12:08 vendor/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ... 4.0K Aug 11 18:28 web/
-rw-r--r--  1 ...  626 Jul  6 15:05 Capfile
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 4.1K Jul  6 15:05 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 167K Jul  6 15:05 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 ...  216 Jul  6 15:05 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 1.2K Jul  6 15:05 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 1.1K Jul  6 15:05 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 1.6K Jul  6 15:05 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 ...    8 Jul  6 15:06 REVISION
-rw-r--r--  1 ... 7.7K Jul  6 15:05 UPGRADE.md
-rw-r--r--  1 ...    7 Jul  6 15:05 VERSION

current/web/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ... 4.0K Aug 11 12:10 bundles/
drwxr-xr-x 4 ... 4.0K Jul  6 15:11 compiled/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ...   47 Jul  6 15:11 js/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  46K Jul  6 15:11 apc.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  11K Jul  6 15:05 apple-touch-icon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 7.0K Jul  6 15:05 apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  728 Jul  6 15:05 app.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  33K Jul  6 15:05 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  20K Jul  6 15:05 favicon.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 4.6K Jul  6 15:05 favicon.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...   51 Jul  6 15:06 image -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/shared/web/image/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...   52 Jul  6 15:06 medias -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/shared/web/medias/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...   66 Aug 10 12:28 robots.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 2.2M Aug 11 03:00 sitemap.xml

current/web/bundles/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 147 Jul  6 15:09 bazingaexposetranslation -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/willdurand/js-translation-bundle/Bazinga/ExposeTranslationBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 121 Jul  6 15:09 ericharddms -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/erichard/dms-bundle/Erichard/DmsBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 126 Jul  6 15:09 farosadmin -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/faros/admin-bundle-legacy/Faros/AdminBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 125 Jul  6 15:09 faroselfinder -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/faros/elfinder-bundle/Faros/ElFinderBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 113 Jul  6 15:09 farosqb -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/faros/qb-bundle/Faros/QBBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 116 Jul  6 15:09 fosjsrouting -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 133 Jul  6 15:09 framework -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 132 Jul  6 15:09 mopabootstrap -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 129 Jul  6 15:09 trsteelckeditor -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/vendor/trsteel/ckeditor-bundle/Trsteel/CkeditorBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...  99 Jul  6 15:09 mysiteadmin -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/src/mysite/AdminBundle/Resources/public/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...  98 Jul  6 15:09 mysitesite -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/releases/201508/src/mysite/SiteBundle/Resources/public/

current/app/
drwxr-xr-x 4 ...   27 Aug 11 18:32 cache/
drwxr-xr-x 3 ... 4.0K Aug 11 12:12 config/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ... 4.0K Jul  6 15:05 DoctrineMigrations/
drwxr-xr-x 8 ...  105 Jul  6 15:06 Resources/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  141 Jul  6 15:05 AppCache.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 4.3K Jul  6 15:05 AppKernel.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  474 Jul  6 15:05 autoload.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  48K Jul  6 15:09 bootstrap.php.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 1.7K Jul  6 15:09 check.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ...  794 Jul  6 15:05 console*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...   50 Jul  6 15:06 logs -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/shared/app/logs/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 1.7K Jul  6 15:05 phpunit.xml.dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 ...  26K Jul  6 15:09 SymfonyRequirements.php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ...   49 Jul  6 15:06 var -> /var/www/html/sites/www.mysite.com/shared/app/var/
```

As you can see there are so many symlinks :(
I have a new installation of symfony 2.1.13 on my wamp server, so :
1. What should I exactly copy from the server ?
2. And where to copy ?
3. How to configure files like AppKernel.php, config.php, parameters.yml ...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are stepped to the task from apposite side

First of all "strange" folders architecture is comming from the nature of the deployment tool "capifony". You can see folder "releases" that keeps all history of releases deployed and folder(symlink) "current" that points to the latest(current) release. Also you can see some symlinks to the folder "shared" that suppose to keep some content that doesn't suppose change from deploy to deploy (like images, logs).

It is possible to explain long how capifony works, but seems it is better to get some quick overview http://capifony.org/

In short words I can say that you can copy the site to local, but it is not the best way. I suppose you need to clone the project from its  repository(most probably git) and setup parameters.yml

You should not change AppKernel.php or config.php

Clone the respository and looks for app/config/parameters.yml.dist that will(should) have initial configuration for the project

PS: you should not copy "current/web/bundles/" but should use "assets install" command to create these assets

PPS: And I believe you should to learn some symfony docs(at least basic) before start to copy the site